# filepicker.io - save canvas as PNG

Tags: javascript, canvas, filepicker.io

Got this to work, and I'm wondering if is the best way:

```
// Take off the "data:image/png;base64," prefix
var b64 = canvas.toDataURL().split(',', 2)[1];
filepicker.store(
  b64, 
  {
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    base64decode: true
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, looks good to me! You may want to parse the b64 data with a slightly more precise regex, but base64encoded data shouldn't have commas in it so you should be OK in general. As the minimum, you can specify `.split(',', 2)`

Comment: I'll add that.

Thought: if you accepted the full data: url, then we wouldn't need the `mimetype: 'image/png', base64decode: true`

Comment: Thought this might save some bandwidth to send binary data with `window.atob( canvas.toDataURL().split(',', 2)[1] )` and `base64decode: false`. It returned OK but was [corrupted](https://www.filepicker.io/api/file/BFsTLioTAS3lmuSUigu3).